# Moving a firebird 2.5 database

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

So currently I have firebird 2.5 installed and running on Windows, working fine but performance is a bit slow.

I have installed 2.5 on Ubuntu, and I can connect to the current database with ISQL easily:

```
connect "192.168.155.112:C:\database\database.FDB" user 'SYSDBA' password 'adminpassword';
```

So I stopped the firebird services on the Windows server, copied the file to the Ubuntu server, and in isql tried to run:

```
SQL> connect "localhost:/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/database.FDB" user 'SYSDBA' password 'adminpassword';
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = m
file /var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/database.FDB is not a valid database
```

Note I have so far tried:

```
~$ sudo adduser `id -un` firebird
[sudo] password for luke: 
The user `luke' is already a member of `firebird'.
```

As well as

```
# chown firebird /var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/database.fdb
```

With no luck, if anyone has any idea as to why I might be getting this error, I would be very grateful :)

I am not sure if Super or Classic was used on Windows, however I have tried using both on Ubuntu with the same error message. Windows server version 2.5.6, same version on Linux

Comment: The safe way to move db from one server to another is to make backup ("transportable" when using gbak; "full" when using nbackup) of the db and then restore from it in the other server.

Comment: @ain As nbackup creates a back up of the physical pages of the database, I don't think you can use it to move a database between systems that might have different on disk structures.

Comment: Right, missed that in the doc (http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/nbackup-overview.html) where it is actually listed as a limitation! Haven't had to use the nbackup myself so I'm not really familiar with it...

Comment: Thanks, I needed gbak with -T flag.

Comment: frankly, changing the very computer just to boost performance a little looks like overkill. I think you'd start with analyzing the real problems - like poor SQL requests or non-optimized settings. Groton/Interbase/Firebird comes form ancient times where top priority was using as few resources of computer as possible, speed did not matter. Since performance tuning is not "one size fit all" task - those defaults were not revised officially. So if you are suffering from poor application design or FB avoiding using computer resources - you would just move those problems to new server

Comment: Frankly - Embedded/Classic/Super in 2.5 are rather different and have different application expectations. So, if you did not checked even that... Bad luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to backup the database using gbak, and then restore it using gbak.

To backup:

```
gbak -backup employee D:\backups\employee.fbk
```

To restore:

```
gbak -c /backups/employee.fbk employee
```

Where `employee` is either the path or the alias of the database.

See also the [gbak manual](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gbak/firebird-gbak.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I needed gbak with -T flag.

Comment: @crooksey (T)ransportable should be the default, IIRC.